# See if a single string is containing something similar in the List with custom Class

Tags: c#, list

My question is, I'm trying to compare if the anchor.name are containing anything in the List. The problem is the list is with a custom class, and I only want to see if the name have contain anything in the GUID that is in the List.

```
         anchor.name = $"Anchor{id}{anchor.name}";
            var tem = gameData_List.showing_my_loading_list.Select(x => x.guid);
            
            if (anchor.name.Contains(tem.ToString()))
            {
                Debug.Log("Spotted Saved GameOBJ");
            }
```

The Class variables

```
[Serializable]
public class MySecondGameList
{
    public Guid guid;
    public string readable_guid;
    //public GameObject anchor_gameobject;
}
```

Right now when I Debug, nothing shows up so I guess I messed something up here. Because I know that it is a match since I can see the GUID in the inspector knowing that anchor.name is contained.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your code like that:

```
anchor.name = $"Anchor{id}{anchor.name}";
var exists = gameData_List.showing_my_loading_list
    .Any(x => anchor.name.Contains(x.guid.ToString());

if (exists)
{
    Debug.Log("Spotted Saved GameOBJ");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code returns a list

```
var tem = gameData_List.showing_my_loading_list.Select(x => x.guid);
```

You're trying to make the list GUID here, but it won't return a value.

```
if (anchor.name.Contains(tem.ToString()))
```

You get type info, for example:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Guid]
```

If you need one, you can use e.g.,

```
var tem = gameData_List.showing_my_loading_list.Select(x => x.guid).FirstOrDefault();
```